# do while with prompt that ends when correct answer given from user

Tags: javascript, do-while, prompt

I am new to coding and have been set a task using a do while and prompt. I have created the code below. If I put anything other than Gryffindor it states 'That is not the house for you, try again!' so when I try again it, instead of repeating that, it returns to the original prompt of asking which house they will be in. Could someone help me correct it? Thank you.

```
var house;

do {house = prompt("With which house will you be placed? Please enter Gryffindor, Ravenclaw, Hufflepuff, or Slytherine!");
if (prompt == 'Hufflepuff' || 'Ravenclaw' || 'Gryffindor');
    house = prompt('That is not the house for you, try again');
} while (house != 'Gryffindor'); 
house = alert ("Yes that is the house for you!")
```

I want it to keep repeating 'That is not the house for you, try again' until the user types Gryffindor rather than go back to "With which house will you be placed? Please enter Gryffindor, Ravenclaw, Hufflepuff, or Slytherine!"

This will be an easy fix for someone and I am still working on it myself with tutorials etc. but I am new to coding so any help you could give would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of an infinite loop `while(true)` and `break` if the right answer is given. `break` will exit out of the nearest loop.

```js
do {
  const house = prompt("With which house will you be placed? Please enter Gryffindor, Ravenclaw, Hufflepuff, or Slytherine!");
  if(house == 'Gryffindor')
  {
    break;
  }
  alert('That is not the house for you, try again');
} while (true);
alert("Yes that is the house for you!")
```

However this lacks the clarity of [one of the other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75939277/219661). Leaving this here as it's a natural progression from your code to something that works - but if you want the *better* code go with the other answer!

Comment: I mean, in that case you might just want to get rid of the `do ... while` altogether (its not recommended anyway as a flow) and just use `while( true ){ ...if(){ break }... }`

Comment: @somethinghere sure, it doesnt really matter that that point if its a `do..while` or a `while` loop

Comment: I understand this works, but I feel adding the unnecessary `do` etc... just makes the whole thing harder to comprehend. There are _very_ few cases where a `do...while` loop is better, simply because of how the flow is read by the developer in code.

Comment: @somethinghere I couldn't agree more! Hence my update to this answer and my coment below yours

Comment: using the infinite loop has worked perfect thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way would be to not use the `do ... while` loop. It's a bit of a confusing control flow to use anyway, so this is a lot easier: just use a `while` loop itself!

```js
let house = prompt( "With which house will you be placed? Please enter Gryffindor, Ravenclaw, Hufflepuff, or Slytherine!");
 
// Just repeat the question until your value is equal to Gryffindor
while( house !== "Gryffindor" ) house = prompt( "That is not the house for you, try again" );

alert( "Yes that is the house for you!" )
```

If you insist on a `do ... while` loop (note: not recommended), the solution is to not have an if condition - your `while` is essentially that. As long as the code in your `while` condition evaluates to true, it will do another round of `do`:

```js
let house = prompt( "With which house will you be placed? Please enter Gryffindor, Ravenclaw, Hufflepuff, or Slytherine!");
 
// It's best _not_ to go to your do..while at all if your condition is met
// The issue, obviously, is that you have to repeat the condition twice!
// That's clearly against the "Don't Repeat Yourself" principle.

if( house !== "Gryffindor" ) do {
   house = prompt( "That is not the house for you, try again" );
} while( house !== "Gryffindor" )

alert( "Yes that is the house for you!" )
```

Why is it not recommended? Because a `do ... while` loop is pretty confusing, your `condition` is only listed after a lot of code, inverse to how it is in most conditions (like `if` or `switch`). I have never seen a `do ... while` code in production anywhere, and it's best to keep it that way.

Comment: Gets my upvote for being the clearer way to do it. My answer was trying to stick closer to the OPs code for clarity.

Comment: I used a while loop but they have asked that we use a do while with a prompt. We are in the early stages of the course, so don't know everything yet. I am doing a lot of self study but I am stuck at this point. Thanks for you help though.

Comment: I have amended my answer with the way to do it... but again, don't do it! Your teachers are teaching you bad practices.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (prompt == 'Hufflepuff' || 'Ravenclaw' || 'Gryffindor')
```

If you want to compare variable to different values you will need to repeat the comparison like

```
if (prompt == 'Hufflepuff' || prompt == 'Ravenclaw' || prompt == 'Gryffindor')
```

Alternatively, you can use a switch statement like

```js
switch (prompt) {
    case 'Hufflepuff':
    case 'Ravenclaw':
    case 'Gryffindor':
        // prompt is either Hufflepuff | Ravenclaw | Gryffindor
        break;
    default:
        // else
        break;
}
```